# Base64 -> AJAX -> PHP writes 0 byte file on Android stock browser

Tags: php, android, ajax, canvas

overflowers!

I've been having a strange problem with saving a file to directory on my server. The flow is as follows:

1. Generate an image from canvas data.
2. Write the image to my server, via AJAX, using PHP. (permissions for the directory are 777)
3. Profit.

The only hiccup I have so far is when using the stock Android 'Browser' browser. **I've been able to successfully save the image** using my list of supported browsers for this project. (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, IE9+). However, when I test on the Android browser, PHP *is* saving a file, to the correct directory, but at 0 bytes. I am testing on Android v. 4.1.1

**My question is why in this one case am I getting a 0 byte file? How can I remedy this?**

I've been all over Google and stackoverflow trying to find an answer, and must have tested about twenty different solutions thus far, to no avail. I'm wondering if the mistake is something I'm easily missing, as I've been staring at the same code for so long.

**Here is the AJAX call:** (CoffeeScript)

```
$.ajax
        type: "POST"
        url: "#{servicesSrc}image-utils.php"
        data:
            post_method: "save_image"
            image_data: image.src
            name_prefix: @currentServiceString + "_"
        success: (response) =>
            doStuff(response) # <-- redacted method name
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            console.error("storeTempUserImage :: Error: #{textStatus}", errorThrown)
```

**and the PHP:** ('REDACTED/FILE/PATH') is correct, and used in every scenario, but I can't display.

```
$randomID = get_random_string();
$imageData = $_POST["image_data"];
$imageData = str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "", $imageData);
$imageData = str_replace(" ", "+", $imageData);
$data = base64_decode($imageData);
$namePrefix = (isset($_POST["name_prefix"])) ? $namePrefix = $_POST["name_prefix"] : $namePrefix = "";
$absoluteURL = $namePrefix.$randomID.".jpg";
$destinationURL = "REDACTED/FILE/PATH" . $absoluteURL;
$fp = fopen($destinationURL, "wb");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
echo $absoluteURL;
```

**and a sample output of a properly saved image, and an improperly saved image:**
twitter_jKbxRIt3NRw8Nd1ucJFcDSrMUBPs9H7M.jpg 98 KB (97,866 bytes)
twitter_LLAwIET5VJDO4LXvD4O0hsngnj2UYata.jpg 0 B (0 bytes)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does `image_data` contain anything when posted from the Android Browser? How is `image.src` retrieved? It looks more like empty data is passed to the PHP script than there being an error with the script.

Comment: Excellent observation. Your comment helped me realize that part of the problem was outside of the AJAX/PHP, pertaining to the image data. Once I have the problem solved, I'll comment with my findings, and mark this as solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thank you to @pilsetnieks for the help. The solution was mostly outside of what I explained above. I was using the PHP method above to handle both jpegs and pngs.

Obviously,

```
$imageData = str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "", $imageData);
```

would only handle a jpeg image. To resolve, I used the following line to handle both jpegs and pngs:

```
$imageData = substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
```

Additionally, I removed the extension from this line, so the file could be either type:

```
$absoluteURL = $namePrefix.$randomID.".jpg";
```